# Error when compiling gcc 4.6.1 C++0x threading code on MacOSX Lion

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c++11

When compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void hello()
{
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
        cout << "starting" << endl;
        thread t(hello);
        t.join();
        cout << "ending" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

using:

```
$ g++-4.6.1 -std=c++0x -pthread threading.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
threading.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
threading.cc:13:2: error: ‘thread’ was not declared in this scope
threading.cc:13:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t’
threading.cc:14:2: error: ‘t’ was not declared in this scope
```

This is on MacOSX Lion with a custom built gcc 4.6.1. All the other c++0x features that are valid for gcc 4.6 works like a charm. Is this a MacOSX specific error?

Comment: I don't know what's happening, but I know I never use -pthread; in stead I use `-lpthread` at the end (!) of the compiler options

Comment: It might still be in `std::tr1`. C++11 was not official when 4.6 was released.

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but doesn't -pthread link in posix threads? This isn't needed by your project.

Comment: Disregard, it doesn't seem like `thread` was in `std::tr1` to begin with. I'm not certain it's implemented in 4.6. Their library support page in only for SVN checkouts, not specific versions. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x

Comment: It's the same error when replacing -pthread with -lpthread

Comment: It worked in linux when i followed this guide: http://blog.scalebit.com/2011/04/compiling-gcc-46-in-ubuntu-1010-for-c11.html but i can not get it to work in osx lion.

Comment: @okorz001: I have no trouble using C++0x threads (including futures and async) from 4.6.1 on linux - however I _need to_ manually specify libpthread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://gcc.gnu.org/PR50196 - Mac OS X doesn't support some parts of pthreads that we rely on. Building the latest version won't help, but it might be fixed for GCC 4.7

Comment: Thanks. Now i have a bug to track.

Comment: I've closed that bug as fixed - your example code should work in GCC 4.7

Answer (score 5):

`std::thread` (and the rest of the C++11 thread library) is only available for some of the platforms supported by gcc 4.6.1. Unfortunately for you, MacOSX is not one of those platforms.

My commercial [Just::Thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) library provides the C++11 thread facilities for 32-bit MacOSX with gcc 4.5, but gcc 4.6 is not supported yet.

Comment: Thanks. Where can i get this kind of information on what things are supported and on what platforms? Do you think that the std::thread is available if i build the latest from the source repository?